# Face Authentication with Google Cloud Vision API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-vision

1- I am using Google Cloud Vision API for face authentication in spring boot.
2- I have created an Account on Google Cloud Console and download a Json key file.
3- I use this Json file in my project and get the response of face data from image like this:

```
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/025kyy
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Forehead
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.9846564
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.9846564
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/0jyfg
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Glasses
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.9844217
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.9844217
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/03q69
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Hair
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.9835347
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.9835347
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/019nj4
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Smile
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.9771221
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.9771221
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/0h8jxfl
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Vision care
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.9488289
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.9488289
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/027n3_
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Eyebrow
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.93961227
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.93961227
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/015h_t
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Beard
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.9188007
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.9188007
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/01k9lj
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Jaw
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.8822703
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.8822703
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/0dzd8
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Neck
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.87822306
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.87822306
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/0j272k5
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Eyewear
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.8768612
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.8768612
```

But Now I have save these detail in my database and comparing the face data at the time of face authentication. But it's not work.

I am doing this(GCP) for the first time. So I don't know how to compare two faces here.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing concepts here.

The feature you are using is something called [face detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces) which detects faces and its features (position, mood, etc) on a image - without identifying unique characteristics from each face that could be used to build a database of faces.

To perform something as face authentication, you do need something called [face recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_recognition_system) where, in summary, you build a base of known faces embeddings and perform a similarity search of a new face against this database.

Google Vision API doesn't provide face recognition mechanisms as it goes against the [Google AI Principles](https://ai.google/principles/).

Comment: Can we use Amazon Rekognition for face authentication with java?

Comment: I have no idea.